# perl how can I append STDOUT of list form system call of perl script to a file

Tags: arrays, perl, stdout, whitespace, filehandle

My `bosswrap.pl` will generate arbitrary arrays containing whitespace in the elements. It repeatedly sends the array by a system call to `wrapped.pl`, which creates STDOUT based on the array.

Subsequently, `bosswrap.pl` must append the STDOUT of `wrapped.pl` to a file which `bosswrap.pl` controls. That is where I am stuck. First `wrapped.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
print "inside $0\n";
my $countarrayelements=0;
for my $item ( @ARGV ) {
        $countarrayelements++;
        print "$countarrayelements: |$item|\n"; 
    }
```

Then `bosswrap.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; 
my $fileresult = "trash.txt";
unlink $fileresult; # rm any existing file
my $handlefileresult; 
my @array = ( 5, "don't you . . . ", "\x09\x21", "\x3f  \x21" );
my $count=0;
print "inside $0\n";
for my $element ( @array ) {
    $count++;
    print "$count\t|$element|\n";
}

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553031/calling-a-shell-command-with-multiple-arguments
#list form: command line arguments pass verbatim, avoid shell interpolation  
system("wrapped.pl", @array) == 0 or die "system failed: \$? = $?";

#This block sends the return code, not the STDOUT, to handlefileresult
open( $handlefileresult, ">> ", $fileresult) || die "$0: can't open $fileresult for appending$!";
print $handlefileresult "not a system call\n";
print {$handlefileresult} system("wrapped.pl", @array) == 0 or die "system failed: \$? = $?";
close ( $handlefileresult ) || die;

#In the following block, select unfortunately will not redirect output of system call:
open( $handlefileresult, ">> ", $fileresult) || die "$0: can't open $fileresult for appending$!";
select $handlefileresult; 
print "selected; BEFORE system call\n";
system("wrapped.pl", @array) == 0 or die "system failed: \$? = $?";
print "selected; AFTER system call\n";
close ( $handlefileresult ) || die;
```

Again, I want to repeatedly call `wrapped.pl` from inside `bosswrap.pl` and put the output of these system calls into `$fileresult`.

One reply @ikegami suggested `use IPC::Run qw( run );` but that throws an error. I run perl on macos. What has to be done to get this to work?

```
> perl --version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2013, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

> bosswrap.pl
Can't locate IPC/Run.pm in @INC (you may need to install the IPC::Run module) (@INC contains: /sw/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level /sw/lib/perl5 /sw/lib/perl5/darwin /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /Users/BNW/u/kh/bin/bosswrap.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/BNW/u/kh/bin/bosswrap.pl line 3.
>
```

Based on [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module) I did

```
> cpan IPC::Run
<snip>
Appending installation info to /Users/BNW/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/perllocal.pod
  TODDR/IPC-Run-20180523.0.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

And then rebooted this MacBook Pro 10.14.6. But I get apparently the same error:

```
> bosswrap.pl
Can't locate IPC/Run.pm in @INC (you may need to install the IPC::Run module) (@INC contains: /sw/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level /sw/lib/perl5 /sw/lib/perl5/darwin /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /Users/BNW/u/kh/bin/bosswrap.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/BNW/u/kh/bin/bosswrap.pl line 3.
>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why-can't-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system\(\)%3f)

Answer (score 2):

`STDOUT` and Perl's default output handle (as set using `select`) are process-specific variables the OS knows nothing of. An executed program does not inherit these. It does inherit the parent's file descriptors, the underlying system handles.

I would let [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run) or [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run3) do the hard work for me.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ "wrapped.pl", @array ],
   '>>', $fileresult;

die("wrapped.pl killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("wrapped.pl exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $ ?>> 8;
```

It is also possible to do with low-level core module [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Open3)

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null')
   or die("Can't open \"/dev/null\": $!\n");
open(local *CHILD_STDOUT, '>>', $fileresult)
   or die("Can't append to \"$fileresult\": $!\n");

my $pid = open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&CHILD_STDOUT', '>&STDERR',
   "wrapped.pl", @array);

waitpid($pid, 0);
die("Can't execute wrapped.pl: $!\n") if $? == -1;
die("wrapped.pl killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("wrapped.pl exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $ ?>> 8;
```

Comment: Attempted this without success and edited my question accordingly. I'm on macos with perl 5.18.4.

Comment: Any reason to believe the error message ("*you may need to install the IPC::Run module*") is wrong?

Comment: I would have no idea how to judge a perl-generated error or warning. I take it at its word. Now have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013279/how-do-i-install-perl-modules-on-macos.

Comment: Followed http://triopter.com/archive/how-to-install-perl-modules-on-mac-os-x-in-4-easy-steps/ ending with `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install IPC::Run'` and `bosswrap.pl` no longer throws the `Can't locate IPC/Run.pm` error.

Answer (score 1):

After installing `IPC::Run` with the help of http://triopter.com/archive/how-to-install-perl-modules-on-mac-os-x-in-4-easy-steps/, the following solution from https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; 
use IPC::Run qw( run );
my $fileresult = "trash.txt";
unlink $fileresult; # rm any existing file
my @array = ( 5, "don't you . . . ", "\x09\x21", "\x3f  \x21", "\x09*\x09" );
my $count=0;
print "inside $0\n";
for my $element ( @array ) {
    $count++;
    print "$count\t|$element|\n";
}
run [ "wrapped.pl", @array ], '>>', $fileresult;
die("wrapped.pl killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("wrapped.pl exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $ ?>> 8;
exit 0;
```